# tight frame for $\mathbb{C}^N$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, orthonormal

I have a question to ask

Prove that if $K\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, then $\{\phi_p[n]=\exp(i2\pi pn/(KN))\}_{0\leq p<KN}$ is a tight frame of $\mathbb{C}^N$, i.e.

$\sum_{k}|\langle f,\phi_p\rangle |^2= A||f||^2$ for some constant $A$.

I only know that $\{e_k[n]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\exp{\frac{i2k\pi n}{N}}\}_{0\leq k<N}$ forms an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^N$, but how do I extend it to the above question?

Comment: What is $f$? How are the $e_k$ an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^N$?

Comment: $f\in\mathbb{C}^N$, and $$\langle e_k,e_l \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{e_k[n]e_k^*[n]} = \delta_{kl}$$